# Renaming a Branch Name, Encounter an error related to branch naming

Tags: node.js, git

I have given the branch name as below while creating the new branch:

```
git checkout -b "working_with_controllers(APIs_Logic)"
```

At the time of creation it didn't throw an error stating "this is the wrong format". But when trying to switch or rename a branch using command:

```
git branch -m working_with_controllers(APIs_Logic)  new-branch working_with_controllers
```

it's showing the error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: You need to keep doing the same thing - _quote_ the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution.

If you want to switch to other branch in which these kind of errors occurs then just put the branch name in double quotes like below:

```
git checkout "working_with_controllers(APIs_Logic)"
```

I tried, and luckily it worked.

And same thing may happen if you try to push the code. Do the same thing as above, means pushing the file by putting the branch name in double quotes

Comment: The lesson to learn here, is to stick to _simple_ branch names :)

Comment: Yes.....I didn't know earlier. But from next time for sure